# How to use RabbitMQ with magento 2.3.x?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to use RabbitMQ with magento 2.3.x in local setup.
If anyone has any good reference link/extension then please provide me.
I referred below links.

- https://www.egrovesys.com/blog/rabbitmq-magento2/
- https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento-2-rabbit-mq-implementation.html

Comment: Links giving wrong, its redirect 404

Comment: Its working for me and others...

Comment: now its working for me

Answer (score 0):

Install RabbitMQ in your server and configure it in your `app/etc/env.php`.
It will look like the file below.

[image: Magento 2 RabbitMQ]

You can run this command below to check if there are queues created, if not, run the setup upgrade.

```
python3 /usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin --host rabbitmq -u username -p ysgnrv1l8ht1zaqvfo2pdqu9fhwc9czi list queues
```